# Principal component analysis dimension reduction in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I have to implement my own PCA function function Y,V = PCA(data, M, whitening) that computes the first M principal
components and transforms the data, so that y_n = U^T x_n. The function should further
return V that explains the amount of variance that is explained by the transformation.

I have to reduce the dimension of data D=4 to M=2 > given function below <

```
def PCA(data,nr_dimensions=None, whitening=False):
""" perform PCA and reduce the dimension of the data (D) to nr_dimensions
Input:
    data... samples, nr_samples x D
    nr_dimensions... dimension after the transformation, scalar
    whitening... False -> standard PCA, True -> PCA with whitening

Returns:
    transformed data... nr_samples x nr_dimensions
    variance_explained... amount of variance explained by the the first nr_dimensions principal components, scalar"""
if nr_dimensions is not None:
    dim = nr_dimensions
else:
    dim = 2
```

what I have done is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats

from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import pdb

import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets

#covariance matrix
mean_vec = np.mean(data)
cov_mat = (data - mean_vec).T.dot((data - mean_vec)) / (data.shape[0] - 1)
print('Covariance matrix \n%s' % cov_mat)

#now the eigendecomposition of the cov matrix
cov_mat = np.cov(data.T)
    eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)
    print('Eigenvectors \n%s' % eig_vecs)
    print('\nEigenvalues \n%s' % eig_vals)

# Make a list of (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]
```

This is the point where I don't know what to do now and how to reduce dimension.

Any help would be welcome! :)

Comment: Is the number of samples higher or the number of features?

Comment: Also what are `x` and `U`? in your code you only have `data`

Comment: see my answer cheers

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a simple example `for the case` where the initial matrix A that contains the samples and features has `shape=[samples, features]`

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import cov
from numpy.linalg import eig

# define a matrix
A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(A)

# calculate the mean of each column since I assume that it's column is a variable/feature
M = mean(A.T, axis=1)
print(M)

# center columns by subtracting column means
C = A - M
print(C)

# calculate covariance matrix of centered matrix
V = cov(C.T)
print(V)

# eigendecomposition of covariance matrix
values, vectors = eig(V)
print(vectors)
print(values)

# project data
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T)
print(P.T)
```

Answer (score 0):

PCA is actually the same as singular value decomposition, so you can either use `numpy.linalg.svd`:

```
import numpy as np
def PCA(U,ndim,whitening=False):
    L,G,R=np.linalg.svd(U,full_matrices=False)
    if not whitening:
        L=L @ G
    Y=L[:,:ndim] @ R[:,:ndim].T
    return Y,G[:ndim]
```

If you want to use the eigenvalue problem, then assuming that the number of samples is higher than the number of features (or your data would be underfit), it is inefficient to calculate the spatial correlations (left eigenvectors) directly. Instead, using SVD use the right eigenfunctions:

```
def PCA(U,ndim,whitening=False):
    K=U.T @ U               # Calculating right eigenvectors
    G,R=np.linalg.eigh(K)
    G=G[:,::-1]
    R=R[::-1]
    L=U @ R                 # reconstructing left ones
    nrm=np.linalg.norm(L,axis=0,keepdims=True)  #normalizing them
    L/=nrm
    if not whitening:
        L=L @ G
    Y=L[:,:ndim] @ R[:,:ndim].T
    return Y,G[:ndim]
```